# Allure report collapses tests with null and JSONObject.NULL parameters

Tags: allure

If two set of parameters in @DataProvider differs only with null & JSONObject.NULL param - allure report will collapse 2 tests in 1. Can it be handled by settings somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your parameters have the same `toString()` value. As workaround you can create a parameter wrapper, that will name your params differently. Or you can use separate parameter for that.